# HockeyApp and iOS: unable to add a script in build phase

Tags: ios, xcode, integration, hockeyapp

I am following this guide and get stuck when trying to add a "Run Script" build phase to my project.

[image]

I followed the [step by step guide on the Hockey website](https://www.hockeyapp.net/help/runscriptbuildphase/) too but unfortunately it seems to be disabled somehow on my project.

Here is **what I see**:

[image]

This is **what I should be seeing**:

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

---

**EDIT**:

These are the additional attempts that I have made, all seem to have the option to add the run script disabled:

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you are selecting the target and not the project, in your project inspector, this menu show as disabled if you are selecting the project instead of the target

Comment: @ReinierMelian I have updated the question with a new screenshot. I am unable to do so. I tried selecting the target as well as selecting the project root. Would you be able to highlight from my screenshot what I should have selected instead?

Comment: OK, I will post you 2 images with 2 forms to do this @mm24 ,give one minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing your problem and check in my Xcode results: Happens to me as well, but there is another way to do this and its working, so this images will help you

[image]

[image]

I hope this helps you, Regards